# Oracle sort strings containing section sign §

Tags: oracle, sorting

I'm having trouble getting the right sort order for strings that have the section sign (§) in them.

I've table in Oracle with a column that has the following values

`Act §10
Act M
Act §13(b)(2)
Act § 6
Act Rule 10a- 2
Act § 7
Act § 4
Act S`

The expected sort should be the following:

`Act § 4
Act § 6
Act § 7
Act §10
Act §13(b)(2)
Act M
Act Rule 10a- 2
Act S`

The default binary sort puts the strings with § at the end. I used the nlssort function with the paramter nls_sort=generic_m but that gave me the following:

`Act §10
Act §13(b)(2)
Act § 4
Act § 6
Act § 7
Act M
Act Rule 10a- 2
Act S`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Terms like `Act §13(b)(2)` are very troublesome, because they actually have 4 (5?) components which determine their position.

Comment: The sort in Sybase returns as desired. But recently there was a migration from Sybase to Oracle. I was wondering if there was a combination of flags that would help achieve the desired sort result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the character for the purposes of sorting:

```
WITH testData AS (
    select 'Act §10' as stringVal from dual union all
    select 'Act M' as stringVal from dual union all
    select 'Act §13(b)(2)' as stringVal from dual union all
    select 'Act § 6' as stringVal from dual union all
    select 'Act Rule 10a- 2' as stringVal from dual union all
    select 'Act § 7' as stringVal from dual union all
    select 'Act § 4' as stringVal from dual union all
    select 'Act S' as stringVal from dual
)

SELECT t.stringVal
FROM testData t
ORDER BY REPLACE(t.stringVal, '§', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the actual table has hundreds of entries. In my post, I just provided a tiny sample. To me, it seems doing this programmatically would be easier. I was hoping to avoid that because this particular table is used in quite a few places and is joined with other tables in different places. I'd have to write a utility function to sort each result set in the program before displaying them on the actual UI.

Comment: @theprogrammer What do you mean by "doing it programatically"? If you want a universal solution, just replace all the bad characters in your actual dataset. You're not going to be able to universally change how sorting works; you'll need to either change the data or change all your queries.

Comment: This won't sort by all the sub paths correctly (most likely).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen From OP's comments, it sounds like they were just using the default sort in Sybase (which happened to put `§` before alphabet characters). So, presumably, there isn't any additional logic beyond sorting the sub-paths alphabetically.

Comment: `Act §10` certainly seems to be expected before `Act §13(b)(2)`.  And also, the OP seems to want `§` records to come before records which do not have this symbol.

Comment: @JoshEller By programmatically I meant sorting the result set in Java. Using nls_sort=generic_m achieves what I'm looking for except for the part where there is a space after §. In my actual data, strings that have a § in them are followed by either a space or a digit. § followed by space should come before § followed by a digit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, `Act  §10` is alphabetically before `Act  §13(b)(2)`, since `0` is alphabetically before `3`. For the sample data, this achieves the exact sort specified... If OP wants something different, they should update the sample data.

Comment: @JoshEller your solution is right. My apologies...I wasn't paying close attention to the 'order by' clause at the end. For whatever reason, I was thinking the returned result set had § replaced with ''. My brain wasn't working :)

Answer (score 3):

If *everything else fails* add a virtual column that defines the required transformations and sort on this column.

example

```
alter table tab
add  col_order as (replace(col,'§ ','§0'));
```

Note that this is only a sample transformation to address the presented data, you'll have to work hard to get the correct replace for you full data.

*The main problem I see, you must fill all parts of the column, that should be interpreted as numbers and are blank, with zeroes.*

Now query sorting on the new column `col_order`

```
select * from tab order by col_order;
COL             COL_ORDER                                    
--------------- ---------------------------------------------
Act § 4         Act §04                                      
Act § 6         Act §06                                      
Act § 7         Act §07                                      
Act §10         Act §10                                      
Act §13(b)(2)   Act §13(b)(2)                                
Act M           Act M                                        
Act Rule 10a- 2 Act Rule 10a- 2                              
Act S           Act S
```

Comment: In OP's expected sort, spaces come before alphanumeric.